# find the minimum value of subarray kahn Academy

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, computer-science, sub-array

This Kahn Academy Question asks to find the minimum value in sub-array starting at the 2nd index, my algorithm is returning 4 but it hasn't prompted me saying that i am correct.

I am wondering where my code is flawed or could be better. thanks :)
/////////////////////////////////////////

```
var indexOfMinimum = function(array, startIndex) {

// Set initial values for minValue and minIndex,
// based on the leftmost entry in the subarray:

var minValue = array[startIndex];
var minIndex = startIndex;

for ( var i = minIndex + 1; i < array.length; i++){

 //iterate through array
    if (array[i] < minValue) { 
        minValue = array[i];
        minIndex = array[minValue];
        minIndex = array.indexOf(minValue);  
    }
}
// Loop over items starting with startIndex, updating minValue and minIndex     as needed:
return minIndex;
}; 
var array = [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14];   
var index = indexOfMinimum(array, 2);
```

Comment: What are you doing there with `minIndex`? It seems it should be `minIndex = i;` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want a simple change and have `minIndex = i;`

You are currently scanning the entire array which might return results before your starting index nit to mention the inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
minIndex = array[minValue];
minIndex = array.indexOf(minValue);
```

You are setting `minIndex` twice. One time with a value from the array, and another time in the next line with a search for the index. And while you have already the index of the actual position, you can directly assign it to `minIndex`.

```
minIndex = i;
```

```js
var indexOfMinimum = function (array, startIndex) {
    var minValue = array[startIndex],
        minIndex = startIndex,
        i;

    for (i = minIndex + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = array[i];
            minIndex = i;                                    // assign here the index
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
};

var array = [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14],
    index = indexOfMinimum(array, 2);

console.log(index);
```